# Leaper if expression is faulty

Tags: java, leap-year

```
import java.util.*;

public class LeapYear {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput = scan.nextInt();
        boolean leapYearisTrue = false;

        while ( userInput != 0 ) {
            if (userInput % 4 == 0) {
                if ( (userInput % 100 == 0) && (userInput % 400 != 0) ) {
                    leapYearisTrue = false;
                    System.out.println (leapYearisTrue);
                }
                else {
                    leapYearisTrue = true;
                    System.out.println (leapYearisTrue);
                }
                userInput = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I input a value that IS a leap year, the program runs smoothly and does what it's supposed to:

```
2000
true
1960
true
400
true
```

but whenever I input a non-leap year, it doesn't print false and would no longer print that a number is a leap year:

```
403
400
2000 ( this is a leap year , yet it doesn't print true)
2004
```

Comment: You are missing an If ..else condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an `else` condition to `if (userInput % 4 == 0)` condition.

Comment: Worked like a Charm, you are a god. I'm going to make you an answer in 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LeapYear {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Enter the year: \n");    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput = scan.nextInt();
        boolean leapYearisTrue = false;

        while (userInput != 0) {
            if (userInput % 4 == 0) {
                if (userInput % 100 == 0) {
                    if (userInput % 400 != 0) {
                        leapYearisTrue = true;
                        System.out.println(leapYearisTrue);
                    }
                } else {
                    leapYearisTrue = true;
                    System.out.println(leapYearisTrue);
                }
                userInput = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```